# Method in the type is not applicable to the arguments

Tags: java, object, arguments, processing

i've looked through many posts on here and couldn't quite see the solution I need...

I'm getting the error:

```
the method initTimer(untitled.Object, String, int int) in the type untitled.TimerClass is not applicable for the arguments (untitled.Toon, String, int, int)
```

and it's driving me crazy.

```
    timers.initTimer(character, "regenAdd", 0,3);
```

The above line is the one throwing the error and the following is the function:

```
public void initTimer(final Object obj, final String method, int delay, int period) {
delay*=1000;
period*=1000;

final Class<?> unknown = obj.getClass();

new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
  public void run() {
    try {
      //get the method from the class 
      Method whatToDo = unknown.getMethod(method, null);
      try {
        //invoke() the object method
        whatToDo.invoke(obj);
      } catch(Exception e) {
        println("Exception encountered: " + e);
      }
    } catch(NoSuchMethodException e) {
      println("Exception encountered: " + e);
    }
    runState = getTimerState();

    if (!runState) {
      println("timer dead");
      this.cancel();
    }
  }
}
, delay, period);
}
```

Thanks in advance to anybody who can help with this :)

Additional info:

> runState is a boolean just incase you couldn't guess and
>   character is an instance of the Toon class; the above method is within
>   the TimerClass class and 'timers' is an instance of that class.

Comment: `untitled.Object` that's really bad choice for a class name. You should consider renaming it. You are trying to pass `untitled.Toon` where `untitled.Object` is expected.

Comment: Can you post the code which is causing the error? Ie the code that calls this method. Show the types of the variables being passed in too

Comment: I've renamed it to `theGame` now so wherever it says `untitled` will now be that. The idea is to pass an unknown object to the function so it can be used for multiple classes. @Bohemian i've posted the code that causes the error and stated the variable types =)

Comment: Does `untitled.Toon` extend `untitled.Object`?

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you very much good sir, your question has solved my problem! If you post it as an answer I can hit accept in it =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message

> the method `initTimer(untitled.Object, String, int int)` in the type `untitled.TimerClass` is not
>   applicable for the arguments `(untitled.Toon, String, int, int)`

is due to the fact that `untitled.Toon` does not extend `untitled.Object`. It extends `java.lang.Object` of course, which is why the reason is not immediately obvious from the source code.

Answer (score -1):

Also, another error is initTimer(untitled.Object, String, int) is being called as (untitled.Toon, String, int, int) - notice the difference in number of arguments - 1 int in method declaration and 2 int in calling the method.

Please remember to correct that also.

Comment: You should recount the amount of `int` parameter for `#initTimer`.